# mysql - #1109 - Unknown table '...' in field list

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Yes I have read other queries with this title, and they're either unanswered or the answers given are irrelevant. This is in a WordPress installation. The Unknown table is one of the core WordPress tables, so it should exist, no?
The output, in phpmyadmin, is

> #1109 - Unknown table 'baqhllRepostmeta' in field list.

A table was created

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS baqhllReacf_digital;
CREATE TABLE baqhllReacf_digital ( 
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY 
    . . .
```

A query was run

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `baqhllReacf_digital` (post_id, ....) 
SELECT `baqhllRepostmeta`.post_id .....
```

Does the table exist?

[image: phpmyadmin navbar]

It would seem so, yet still the error persists.

I know the SQL is OK. I've run it on two other website databases. so why in this case does it fail?

Comment: That image does not contain `baqhllReacf_digital` So it would seem it does not exist

Comment: The destination table does exist.  Its the source table it can't find and thaty exists as well. as the image shows.

Answer (score 0):

Digging deeper, I found some corruption in a table that referenced a field and table that had had some of the back ticks removed.